# Excel geting negative time instead of 0 value

Tags: excel

Hi Long story short i have spent a couple days trying to figure out why its giving me minus values instead of minus the formula im using for the F column is =E9-TIME(8,0,0) which works but for the blank sections its giving me minus value also the total for that column is also negative, i am also seeking help on the regular hours section where it displays the regular hours which is any time less then 8 hours, bare in mind overtime is 8 hours onward if that helps:

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: If you subtract a number from `0`, why would you expect anything other than a negative result?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  But perhaps:

**Overtime**

```
=MAX(0,E9-TIME(8,,))
```

**Regular hours**

```
=E9-F9
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid negative values on empty cells, You may use an if statement as below

> =IF(E9="","",E9-TIME(8,0,0))

It means, if *E9* is empty then answer should be empty cell, otherwise subtract the two values.